# Change dot (.) to comma (,) in R

Tags: statistics, dataset, regression

I have a dataset I am working on in R, however, one of the column values has dot (.) instead of a comma (,) so I think this might be messing up when I am running the regression. Does anyone know what code I should run to change all the dots to commas?

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: If you are reading it in using `read.table` and all numeric columns use comma instead of dot then specify the `dec=","` argument.  Note the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page which specifies that questions should include complete self contained minimal reproducible examples.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a dataframe named df

```
df %>% mutate_all(funs(str_replace(., "\\.", ",")))
```

If its for one column only

```
df %>%  mutate(col1 = gsub("\\.", ",", col1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is a character vector inside a dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(var = c("5.1", "30", "..", "75.234.4423.5"))
```

**With gsub**

```
df$var <-  gsub("\\.", ",", df$var)
```

**With stringi and purrr**

```
library(stringi)
library(purrr)

df$var <- modify_if(df$var, stri_detect_fixed(df$var, "."), 
                    ~stri_sub_replace_all(., stri_locate_all_fixed(., "."), replacement=","))
```

**Output**

```
df

            var
1           5,1
2            30
3            ,,
4 75,234,4423,5
```

I used `purrr::modify_if` with the predicate `stri_detect_fixed(df$var, ".")` so that the values without any dots (in my example, `30`) are not converted to `NA` by `stringi::stri_sub_replace_all`.
The `stringi` version is more flexible for other purposes, you can pass functions inside the replacement argument when you want a dynamic replacement value.

I cannot comment on if it will help your regression analysis. I simply answered by giving ways to change dots to commas in a character vector.